# Confirm message to delete custom table when deactivating plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, confirmation

I'm totally new to WordPress and php. I have a custom table in my Wordpress plugin and I want to delete the custom table when deactivating the plugin (NO when uninstalling it).
This is easy to accomplish but before deleting the table I want to ask for confirmation.

```
function va_deactivation() {
.... //unregisters settings

//Asks for confirmation - Code here


//If answer is yes proceed to delete. If no, doesn't execute the following code 
global $wpdb;
$pa_table = $wpdb->prefix."tableName";
$sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$pa_table;
$wpdb->query( $sql );

}
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.deactivate a').click(function (e) {
        let url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        let regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
                params = {},
                match;
        while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
            params[match[1]] = match[2];
        }
        if(params.plugin === "{plugin_name}%2F{plugin_name}.php"){
            let delete_confirm = confirm("You are going deactivate this plugin");
            if (delete_confirm !== true) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I used this in my case

but its better to use [register_uninstall_hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_uninstall_hook/)